# Find all permutations of words from list that fits in given word

Tags: python, depth-first-search

If I had the word "sometime" and I have the list of words

valid_words: `["some","time","rome","sometime","so","me"]`

I want to output the result

result = `[["so","me","time"],["some","time"],["sometime"]]`

I know I should be using DFS, but I have no idea how to code it. I struggle with permutations. Can somebody help me?

This is what I have so far

```
def letterCombinations(word, valid_words):
    result = []
    def dfs(string_path, i, valid_word_set, curr_string):
      if i == len(word):
        return

      if string_path[:i] in valid_word_set:
        curr_string.append(string_path[:i])
        dfs(string_path[i:], i+1, valid_word_set, curr_string)
      else:
        dfs(string_path, i+1, valid_word_set, curr_string)
        
    for i in range(0, len(word)):
        if word[:i] in valid_words:
          curr_string = [word[:i]]
          dfs(word[i:], i, valid_words, curr_string)
          result.append(curr_string)
    
    return result
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that you have tried with, then we can help you troubleshoot any issues you might have with that. [SO] is not a coding service.

Comment: Add the code you came up with so far, this way we can make suggestions to what to improve and shows that you at least made some efford towards solving your problem

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for you.
It uses recursion to loop through all the combinations and stores found words in set, so you are essentially caching

```py
def letter_combos(word: str, word_dict: list[str]) -> list[list[str]]:
    def dfs(word: str, valid_word_set: set[str], start: int, memo: dict[int, list[list[str]]]) -> list[list[str]]:
        if start in memo:
            return memo[start]
        res: list[list[str]] = []
        if start == len(word):
            res.append([])
        for end in range(start + 1, len(word) + 1):
            if word[start:end] in word_dict:
                list_of_words = dfs(word, valid_word_set, end, memo)
                for lst in list_of_words:
                    res.append([word[start:end]] + lst)
        memo[start] = res
        return res
    return dfs(word, set(word_dict), 0, {})

word = "sometime"
valid_words = ["some", "time", "rome", "sometime", "so", "me"]

print(letter_combos(word, valid_words))

>>> [['so', 'me', 'time'], ['some', 'time'], ['sometime']]
```

You can also use functools lru_cache for this which tidies it up a bit

```py
from functools import lru_cache

def letter_combos(word: str, valid_words: list[str]) -> list[list[str]]:
    @lru_cache(maxsize=None) 
    def dfs(start: int) -> list[list[str]]:
        if start == len(word):  
            return [[]]
        result: list[list[str]] = []
        for end in range(start + 1, len(word) + 1):
            if word[start:end] in valid_word_set:
                for lst in dfs(end):
                    result.append([word[start:end]] + lst)
        return result

    valid_word_set = set(valid_words)
    return dfs(0)

word = "sometime"
valid_words = ["some", "time", "rome", "sometime", "so", "me"]
print(letter_combos(word, valid_words))
```

Comment: Thank you! I just have one question. why do you append an empty list if start == len(word)?

Comment: also what does res.append([word[start:end]] + lst) do?

Comment: Appending the empty list signifies you have reached the end of the word and there are no more characters left to check. This shows there is only one way to split the remaining part of the string which is an empty string.

`res.append([word[start:end]] + lst)` creates the valid combinations. word[start:end] gets the current valid word and then includes the rest of the ways the string can be split

example: `dfs(word, valid_word_set, end, memo)` returns `[["time"]]` then `res.append([word[start:end]] + lst)` will create the list ['some', 'time'] and append it to res

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution basing on [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and generator function:

```
from itertools import permutations

def match_perms(word, valid_words):
    words = valid_words[:]
    if word in words:   # if the whole word is found in words list
        yield (word,)
        words.remove(word)  # excude it from permutations

    for i in range(2, len(words)):
        for p in permutations(words, i):
            if ''.join(p) == word:
                yield p

print(list(match_perms(word, valid_words)))
```

---

```
[('sometime',), ('some', 'time'), ('so', 'me', 'time')]
```

Answer (score 1):

A recursive approach, which also takes into account potential duplicated words using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

word = 'sometime'
valid_words = ['some', 'time', 'rome', 'sometime', 'so', 'me']

def find_comb(word, valid_words, stem=None):
    if stem is None:
        stem = []
    if not isinstance(valid_words, Counter):
        valid_words = Counter(valid_words)
    if word in valid_words:
        yield stem + [word]
    for w in valid_words:
        if word.startswith(w):
            yield from find_comb(word[len(w):],
                                 valid_words-Counter({w: 1}),
                                 stem=stem+[w])  
    
out = list(find_comb(word, valid_words))
```

Output: `[['sometime'], ['some', 'time'], ['so', 'me', 'time']]`

Other examples:

```
list(find_comb('banana', ['banana', 'ba', 'na', 'na', 'nana']))
# [['banana'], ['ba', 'nana'], ['ba', 'na', 'na']]

list(find_comb('banana', ['banana', 'ba', 'na', 'nana']))
# [['banana'], ['ba', 'nana']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def letterCombinations(word, valid_words):
      result = []

    
    def dfs(string_path, valid_word_set, curr_string):
        if not string_path:
            result.append(curr_string[:])  # Append a copy of the current string to the result list
            return
        
        for i in range(1, len(string_path) + 1):
            if string_path[:i] in valid_word_set:
                curr_string.append(string_path[:i])
                dfs(string_path[i:], valid_word_set, curr_string)
                curr_string.pop()  # Backtrack by removing the last element from the current string
    
       valid_word_set = set(valid_words)
       dfs(word, valid_word_set, [])
       return result

    word = "sometime"
    valid_words = ["some", "time", "rome", "sometime", "so", "me"]
    result = letterCombinations(word, valid_words) 
    print(result)
```

I think this will work for you let me know if it will not work